# Missing photos from Google Photos app

Tags: google-photos

My son uploaded about 1000 photos, but when he got home from holiday and logged onto the app, the photos simply weren't there even though when he did the upload, he got a backup successful message.

Is there any way of contacting Google to retrieve them? Could they be sitting on the Google servers somewhere but he just can't see them on his account? He deleted the photos from his phone some days after the upload, but surely this wouldn't sync to the app and remove them from the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for them on the bin folder or [here](https://plus.google.com/u/1/photos/search/%23AutoBackup).